# Get context of newly started activity via startActivityForResult

Tags: android

I am starting an activity via startActivityForResult. Is there any way to get the instance or context of the newly started activity? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean context of a newly started activity. If its an activity it has a Context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of.

When an activity starts another activity, it can pass data to it (call this upstream). When the activity is done, it can return data to the caller (call this downstream). The upstream and downstream communication only happens at the point of invocation and termination respectively.

You seem to need the context of the called activity in the caller. Most likely the calling activity will be put in the "Paused" state when the called activity starts. Even if you were to manage to make the called activity to set the context object to some variable they both can share (e.g. via the global application object), there is no guarantee that the calling activity will be around to make use of the context.

Comment: ok, I had the same feeling, but wasn't sure. Thanks to confirm it.